# jQuery loop function continuously - flip function

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

here is the function: http://jsfiddle.net/bfQMD/25/

How can I flip continuously when hover and stops when hover out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("a").hover(
        function () {
            var self = $(this);
            self.data("hover", true);

            function flip() {
                $(".flipbox").flip({
                    direction:'tb',
                    color: '#fff',
                    onEnd: function(){
                        if (self.data("hover")) {
                            setTimeout(flip,500);
                        }
                    }
                })
            }

            flip();        
        }, 
        function () {
            $(this).data("hover", false);
        }
    );

});
```

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/2BALx/

In the two hover functions, you keep track of whether the mouse is currently hovering and then in the `onEnd` function for each flip, if the mouse is still hovering, you start a new `flip()` after a short delay.  Due to the way the flip plug-in works, you have to use a short delay (it can be super short if you want) because if you try to start the next clip from onEnd directly, it won't start - thus it needs to be on at least a very short timer.